# Python: How to create a new list based on existing list without certain objects

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
a = ['house', 'bikeCT', 'car', 'bike', 'houseCT']
```

I want a new list based on list a without all objects containing `'CT'`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
a = ['house', 'bikeCT', 'car', 'bike', 'houseCT']
b = [x for x in a if 'CT' not in x]
```

Comment: Wow, a blazingly fast answer :)

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed quick.

Answer (score 1):

If your search is more complex than the preferred `in`, you can use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = ['house', 'bikeCT', 'car', 'bike', 'houseCT']  
>>> [s for s in a if not re.match(r'.*e',s)]
['car']
```

or, `endswith`:

```
>>> a = ['house', 'bikeCT', 'car', 'bike', 'houseCTn']
>>> [s for s in a if not s.endswith('CT')]
['house', 'car', 'bike', 'houseCTn']
```

Answer (score 1):

An Easier Way Is To Remove The Items, Rather Than Creating A New One.

```
a = ['house', 'bikeCT', 'car', 'bike', 'houseCT']
```

This Is How Your List Looks. To Dletele Something From It:

```
del a[1]
del a[4]
```

This tells the computer, delete item number one from the list called "a" and delete item number 4 from the list called "a". But remember, in Python, the first thing in your list is called 0, not 1. Your final product should look like this (After You write print(a):

```
['house', 'car', 'bike']
```

Hope This Helps